# Where does this trig. identity hold?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Fix an integer $n\geq1$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it possible to find **ALL** pair of sequences of non-negative integers $(a_k,b_k)$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$, such that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^{2a_k}\theta\cdot \cos^{2b_k}\theta = 1, \qquad \text{for every $\theta$ ?}$$

**Example 1.** If $n=1$, take $a_1=b_1=0$.

**Example 2.** For a given $n$, choose $(a_1,b_1)=(0,n-1)$ else $(a_k,b_k)=(1,n-k)$ if $2\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: "[A]ny $\theta$" means "every $\theta$", right?

Comment: Your problem can be restated simply as: when $\sum_{k=1}^nx^{a_k}(1-x)^{b_k}\equiv 1$.  It is easy to list all $(a_k,b_k)$ for any specific $n$.

Comment: @LSpice: yes, for all $\theta$ or every $\theta$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: How?

Comment: We can list all solutions by listing all possibilities and checking which ones work. The result is an infinite list because adding $k$ to all the $a$'s or all the $b$'s leads to another solution. The result also more interestingly infinite because for any $(1-x)^k$, we can find nonegative $a$'s and $b$'s such that $(1-x)^k + \sum x^{a_i}(1-x)^{b_i} = 0$. (Proof: Obviously $(1-x)+x=1$, and if $(1-x)^n+\sum x^{a_i}(1-x)^{b_i}=1$, then $(1-x)^{n+1}+x+\sum x^{a_i}(1-x)^{b_i+1}=1$.)

Comment: @MattF., I don't understand your claim about adding $k$ to all of the $a$s or all of the $b$s. Surely you require at least one $i$ for which $a_i = 0$ and one $j$ for which $b_j = 0$ because otherwise $\theta = 0$ resp. $\frac \pi2$ makes the whole sum vanish? Also $\theta = \frac \pi4$ gives $\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-a_k - b_k} = 1$.

Comment: Actually that does give an algorithm, albeit inefficient: let $m = \max_k(a_k + b_k)$. Then $m < n$, so consider partitions of $2^{n-1}$ into $n$ powers of $2$ to get candidates for the sums $a_k + b_k$. Since the $a_k, b_k$ are non-negative each sum has a finite number of candidates, so enumerate through the Cartesian product.

Comment: [All solutions up to $n=9$ inclusive](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/87293d7b84b017229ca3395d3d14e411) with pairs ordered lexicographically. The sequence of counts is not in OEIS.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: superb! Thanks.

Comment: In other words, the polynomial $\sum x^{a_k} y^{b_k} - 1$ must be divisible by $x+y-1$. Of course there are many such polynomials, all you need from the quotient $f(x, y)\in \mathbb{Z}[x, y] $ is that $f(x, y) (x+y-1)+1$ has non-negative coefficients.

Comment: (continue) So, $f=r_0+r_1+r_2+\dots+r_k$ for homogeneous $r_i$ of degree $i$, and $r_0=1$, $r_i(x+y)-r_{i+1}$ has non-negative coefficients. A lot of freedom.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I shouldn't have made that first claim, though it can be corrected. And the simpler proof for my second claim is that $(1-x)^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x(1-x)^i=1$.